# ClientIDMode static causes button onclick method to not load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I'm trying to activate some jQuery in my master page from my child page.

However when I include `ClientIDMode="Static"`in the child page (child.aspx) the script calling API (in child.aspx.cs) for my child page will not load. (but I need it to activate jQuery in master)

How do I fix this?

> Update: Both Jquery and onclick work when I set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`. However the jquery will only run for a short while before crashing.

Button in child page (child.aspx)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Enter Value" OnClick="btnEnter_Click" />
```

Script related to child page that calls api (child.aspx.cs)

```
 protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hihi");
        PostRequest("http://localhost:5001/api/submit");       
    }
```

JQuery in master page

```
    $(function () {
            $('#btnEnter').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //180 makes a circle
                startAngle = 180;
                animate();
                $("#foo").show();
                //var auth = document.getElementById("txtAuthority").textContent;
                alert("hi");
            });
        });
```

Comment: well try place the jqury between document.ready function

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi Hi I did include document.ready in my master file but it does not seem to be working. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi `$(function(){...})` is a short version of `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.